# `conda activate <environment>` on Spyder console not working

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I have python 3.7.10, conda 4.12.0, and Spyder 5.0.5 installed on Windows 10, and I can see the list of environments with `conda env list`.

However, when I run `conda activate <environment>`, `CommandNotFoundError` appears:

```
In[1]: conda activate <env>

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
[...] 
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I like to change the environment without running Anaconda navigator (or close Spyder every time I change the environment).

Is there a command that I can run on Spyder console to change the virtual environment? Is it also possible to run different environments on different Spyder consoles?

Answer (score 1):

To change environments you will need to change the interpreter preference and restart the console or create a new one. To change the interpreter preference you can go to `Tools > Preferences > Python Interprer > Use the following Python interpreter` and select there the path for the `python.exe` of the env you want to use.

For more info regarding how to use existing enviroments with Spyder: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: Is it possible to have consoles running in different environments?

Comment: Changes to the Python interpreter preference only affect new consoles or already running consoles when you restart their kernel. If you want to have consoles running in different environments then you just need to change the interpreter and create a new console while not closing the existing consoles and be sure to not restart their kernels. To access the Python interpreter preferences easily you can go to the status bar and click the `Completions:` section and then click `Change default environment on Preferences...`